# GCP External Global Load Balancer Serverless Health Check

Tags: serverless, health-check, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have set up two cloud run services:

- Monolith
- Service 2

I have setup the load balancer's frontend and backend services using Serverless network endpoint group for the two cloud run services.

I am not able to find a way to setup a health check so that I can debug a 502 gateway error that I get on my public IP for the load balancer.

Does anyone know the steps to create a health check. If it is possible at all.

I have tried to replicate the steps here https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#hc-to-bes